# How to add createBottomTabNavigator to same screen with createStackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, tabnavigator

On my home screen (I used App.js as my home), I have createStackNavigator with createAppContainer to map all the screens using React-Navigation.  It worked, and I can explicitly navigate to any of these screens from any screen.  Now I want to add a bottom tab navigation bar to the home screen with "createBottomTabNavigator".

Here's the simplified version of my codes:

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createBottomTabNavigator  } from 'react-navigation';
import Screen1 from './Screens/Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screens/Screen2';
import Screen3 from './Screens/Screen3';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <View><Text>Welcome</Text></View>
      );
   }
 }

 const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
   Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
   Screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
   Screen2: { screen: Screen2 },
   Screen3: { screen: Screen3 },
 });

 export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

I want to add a navigation bar at the bottom like this:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
   Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
   Screen3: { screen: Screen3 },
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

It won't allow two "export default" within the same page.  How can I add the "createBottomTabNavigator" while keeping the "createStackNavigator" to map all my screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Screen1 from './Screens/Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screens/Screen2';
import Screen3 from './Screens/Screen3';
import Screen4 from './Screens/Screen4';

const Home = createStackNavigator({
  Screen1, Screen2
});

const List = createStackNavigator({
  Screen3, Screen4
});

const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home, List
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNav);
```

Here your Home can be `Screen1` and `Screen2` Can be an Item of Screen1 and same for the `Screen3 and Screen4`

Comment: Just a question, when you declare more than one screens for "Home",  and then you add "Home" to the BottomTabNavigator, does the "Home" tab always navigates to the first screen you declared for "Home"?

Comment: First it will navigate as always to the first screen, Example here to screen1 but if you want to add more screen you just need to add that in your home stack as it is like Screen1, Screen2, Screen3. then if you need it navigate to some screen example Screen3 you just call the this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen3', {name: 'somename'}); when you click on some button

Answer (score 1):

You can use code as follows:

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Screen1 from './Screens/Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screens/Screen2';
import Screen3 from './Screens/Screen3';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <View><Text>Welcome</Text></View>
    );
 } 
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: TabNavigator },
  Screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
  Screen2: { screen: Screen2 },
  Screen3: { screen: Screen3 },
});

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Screen3: { screen: Screen3 },
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```